# Video display rotation position changed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, actionscript

I am trying to rotate video display depend on angle. 
I got total 4 angle 0,-90,90,180.

And i make rotation as per following:

```
if(videoAngle == 180)
{
    videoDisplay.rotation = 180;                            
}
else if(videoAngle == 90)
{
    videoDisplay.rotation = -90;
}
else if(videoAngle == -90)
{
    videoDisplay.rotation = 90;
}
```

It rotate the `videoDisplay` but it's x and y position is changed and also `height` and `width`.

I tried many things but didn't succeed. 

 Is there any solution for that?

Comment: `I try many things to set it's x and y but didn't succeed.`  like what???.. you said rotation works fine and still you show working code not problematic code? I would be using `netStream` with `Video` object if you have too many problems since those give better control over the video..

Comment: Any solution for what?  I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I tried like `videoDisplay.x = 100;` with static/fixed value. it will solved issue but not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Video object have rotation point fixed in top left, so you need to put this video in a container (MC or Sprite) with 'x' and 'y' in the center of video.

You can do it in fla but also in code:

```
function putInCenter(display:DisplayObject):Sprite {
    var box:Sprite = new Sprite()
    display.parent.addChild(box)
    box.x = display.x + display.width / 2
    box.y = display.y + display.height / 2
    box.addChild(display)
    display.x = -display.width / 2
    display.y = -display.height / 2
    return box
}

var videoBox:Sprite = putInCenter(videoDisplay)
```

Now you rotate this container instead of "videoDisplay"

```
if(videoAngle == 180)
{
    videoBox.rotation = 180
}
else if(videoAngle == 90)
{
    videoBox.rotation = -90;
}
else if(videoAngle == -90)
{
    videoBox.rotation = 90;
}
```